# Tomcat sending Bad Rquest (Status Code 400) when calling app to app

Tags: tomcat

I have two apps running in Tomcat localhost - app1 and app2. app1 calls app2 using http. However, everytime I call I get a Bad request (Response 400).

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The character [l] is never valid in an IPv6 address.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.readHostIPv6(HttpParser.java:787)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:75)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:45)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(AbstractProcessor.java:288)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareRequest(Http11Processor.java:809)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I have added the following in the catalina.properties

```
tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|{}
```

I also added the following at the startup -

```
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true 
-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH=true
```

I am running Tomcat 9. Any help will be appreciated.